# Different notions of measurability lead to strikingly different (if not opposite) conclusions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space. Let $f \in E^X$.

- $f$ is called $\mu$-***simple*** if $f = \sum_{k=1}^n e_k 1_{A_k}$ where $e_k \in E$ and $(A_k)_{k=1}^n$ is a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sets with finite measure in $\mathcal A$. Let $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of such $\mu$-simple functions.
- $f$ is called $\mu$-***measurable*** if $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence $(f_n)$ in $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$.
- $f$ is called $\mathcal A$-***measurable*** if $f^{-1}(O) \in \mathcal A$ for all open sets $O \subseteq E$.
- $f$ is called $\mu$-***almost separable valued*** if there is a $\mu$-null set $A$ such that $f(A^c)$ is separable.

There is a theorem relating different kinds of measurability notions, i.e.,

> [Theorem 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306079/a-function-f-is-mu-measurable-if-and-only-if-f-is-mathcal-a-measurable) Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be complete and $\sigma$-finite. Then a function $f \in E^X$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if $f$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable and $\mu$-almost separable valued.

The assumptions completeness and $\sigma$-finiteness are both essential in **Theorem 1**.  At page 47 of Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*, we encounter the following paragraph.

> If $\mu$ is a measure on $(X, \mathcal{M})$, we may wish to except $\mu$-null sets from consideration in studying measurable functions. In this respect, life is a bit simpler if $\mu$ is complete.
>
> **Proposition 2.11** The following implications are valid iff the measure $\mu$ is complete:
>
> - a. If $f$ is measurable and $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e., then $g$ is measurable.
> - b. If $f_{n}$ is measurable for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_{n} \rightarrow f \mu$-a.e., then $f$ is measurable.

Previously, Folland defines measurability of a function as follows.

> If $(X, \mathcal{M})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N})$ are measurable spaces, a mapping $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is called $(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})$-**measurable**, or just **measurable** when $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are understood, if $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $E \in \mathcal{N}$.

Folland's **Proposition 2.11** can be expressed in my notations of measurability as follows.

> **Proposition 2.11** The following implications are valid **iff** the measure $\mu$ is **complete**:
>
> - a. If $f$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable and $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e., then $g$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.
> - b. If $f_{n}$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_{n} \rightarrow f \mu$-a.e., then $f$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.

A detailed proof of this proposition can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834174/real-analysis-folland-proposition-2-11-exercise-10-measurable-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1). On the other hand, I proved below related theorem.

> [Theorem 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be $\sigma$-finite, $(f_n)$ a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions, and $f \in E^X$ the $\mu$-a.e. limit of $(f_n)$. Then $f$ is also $\mu$-measurable.

I'm surprised that different notions of measurability lead to strikingly different (if not opposite) results. In particular,

- **Proposition 2.11** uses the measurability criterion that depends only on the $\sigma$-algebra. However, its conclusion depends completely on the completeness of $\mu$.
- **Theorem 2** uses the measurability criterion that depends on both the $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$. However, its conclusion is independent of the completeness of $\mu$.

Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

---

**Update:** In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508061/let-f-g-in-ex-such-that-f-is-mu-measurable-and-f-g-mu-a-e-then-g), with $\mu$-measurability notion I proved the **Proposition 2.11.a** without completeness assumption.